# Not able to deregister node js service running in a kubernetes pods(when pod deleted) from Eureka discovery service

Tags: node.js, kubernetes, netflix-eureka, kubernetes-pod, service-discovery

I am not able to deregister from eureka when a node js service pods are destroyed ? If I stop the node js app by **Ctrl+C** then it deregisters from eureka but not when the kubernetes pod gets destroyed ?

I need help regarding the kubernetes pods deletion process. How the kubernetes pods get destroyed and the main things how it closes the running process and programs inside the pod so that I can deregister from eureka ?

Here is the code I using to deregriter from eureka :

```
    process.stdin.resume();
    
    function exitHandler(options, exitCode) {
        if (options.cleanup) console.log('clean');
        if (exitCode || exitCode === 0) console.log(exitCode);
        if (options.exit) {
            eurekaClient.stop(function (error) {
                process.exit();
            });
        }
    }
    
    //do something when app is closing
    process.on('exit', exitHandler.bind(null, {cleanup: true}));
    
    //catches ctrl+c event
    process.on('SIGINT', exitHandler.bind(null, {exit: true}));
    
    // catches "kill pid" (for example: nodemon restart)
    process.on('SIGUSR1', exitHandler.bind(null, {exit: true}));
    process.on('SIGUSR2', exitHandler.bind(null, {exit: true}));
    
    //catches uncaught exceptions
    process.on('uncaughtException', exitHandler.bind(null, {exit: true}));
```

Comment: so when the pod dies does it not automatically gets deregistered from eureka?

Comment: No, The eureka still show the node service as up instance